# Why is Using JavaScript within PHP for Location Change, Bad Practice?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

Consistently on Stack Overflow, the question of how to redirect a user upon input or after values have been altered is raised, and in PHP, the standard answer is to modify the headers to achieve this.

However, in PHP, headers must be altered at the beginning before any html or text is posted.

So regularly I post my own personal solution, which is as follows:

"End the PHP tag when you would like to perform the redirect and write the following:

```
 <script>
 location.replace("Whatever.php");
 </script>
```

And then finally pick up your PHP tag once more to complete your code."

Everytime I have posted that, the answer has been downvoted to oblivion almost immediately. However, to my knowledge, it works, in it's entirety.

So my question is, why is this downvoted so heavily? What is it about using this solution that is so frowned upon?

Example of Full Usage (excluding escape functions):

```
if(isset($_GET['role'])){ //If value set in GET
   $role = $_GET['role']

   if($role == "Admin"){ ?> // Drop PHP tag

   <script>location.replace("AdminPage.php");</script> //Solution

   <?php else{ ?>

    <script>location.replace("StandardPage.php");</script> //Solution

   <?php } } ?> //Pick up Tag final time and Close isset.
```

Comment: Well if you are redirecting a user there really isn't any point outputting any text or html, so why wouldn't you do a `header('Location...')` instead of waiting for the browser to render the html, run the javascript, and then process the location change.

Comment: But as far as I am aware, you cannot even run or test conditions in PHP, and then make a decision using headers. Which suggests to me that headers for location change is virtually pointless.

Comment: _"run or test conditions in PHP"_ depends on what conditions you are talking about. Obviously you can't test a user's desktop resolution, but you didn't show that in your example, you just showed testing a GET parameter which you can fully test in PHP as you have already shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it does work doesn't mean you shouldn't prefer the more fitting way to do it. So why is a header re-direct preferable, you might ask?

1. JavaScript can be disabled, and if you redirect because of needed authorization (it looks like you're redirecting based on that in your example), someone could just disable JavaScript and see the "secret stuff" on that page, maybe even trigger an action via a link (deletion of data), if the backend is missing the authorization-check.
2. If using a header redirect, that will happen as soon as the client has fetched the headers. No content will have to be transfered (it still might in some cases, but using `exit;` right after the Location header will prevent that). That means less overhead and faster reaction times for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a client can just turnoff the Javascript. So then and there your code is broken immediately.

Don't give client to any chance to alter or break your work flow.

Secondly bad practice because unmanageable. Keep it separate style, scripts and php codes.